# usage of "it has come to my knowledge"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it possible to continue the phrase "it has come to my knowledge that..." without including "that"

The specific line I have in my mind is

> With reference to the above mentioned advertisement dated 8th February 2022, **it has come to
> knowledge that** there is a vacancy for the post of "enter job" in your reputed company and I
> would like to express my interest in that.

disclosure: no i am not applying for a job

Comment: The expression "It has come to my knowledge..." is archaic to the point I didn't even recognize it as legitimate English. The natural phrasing is, "It has come to my **attention**...". The word "that" can be omitted, but it sounds better with it included.

Comment: Hi! Please edit to tell about why you think it might be possible to omit "that." The short answer is "no," but you'll get better answers if you share your thinking.

Comment: @gotube It *has* been common enough, but is mostly archaic: [nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+come+to+my+knowledge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20come%20to%20my%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0). And can you expound (perhaps in an answer) on why you think "that" can be omitted? Also, Adil, note that in the block quote you have "it **is**." This is probably a typo; English used to use "is" instead of "has" with a participle in that way, but that's much much more archaic.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks for the correction about "knowledge". I've amended my comment. I think "that" can be omitted because it feels natural to me. I haven't written an answer because I don't have enough caffeine in my system yet to explain why :)

Comment: @gotube the reason i chose **knowledge** over **attention** is because in this specific scenario, attention seems a bit more sounding like it comes from a higher authority rather than from a jobseeker. Attention lacks humility imo, but i am open for any suggestions

Comment: @AdilMohammed Good point. In that case, "I notice..." works better than either "knowledge" or "attention".

Answer (score 2):

Collins Dictionary:

come to one's knowledge
in British English

But I'd say it's okay in American English too.

There is also: come to one's attention. It is **slightly** different.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/come-to-ones-knowledge [come to one's knowledge](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/come-to-ones-knowledge)

It has come to my attention [that] you have poor grades. [My attention was drawn to or it was brought to my attention by someone]
It has come to my knowledge [that] you have poor grades. [I have learned]

You can leave out the "that".

Comment: It is also oaky in AmE, but this does not address the question. The question was about the need to use "that" along with the phrase, right?

Comment: **It** refers to the fact that the speaker has learned. "The fact **that** X is Y has come to my knowledge". The expression wouldn't make sense without **that**.